# How to programatically retrieve trace data from an E5071C with SCPI commands?

Tags: embedded, gpib

I am working with an Agilent E5071C VNA and am trying to retrieve trace data from the machine. Unlike the docs for other VNAs, I've found the doc for the E5071C to be much harder to follow. What I am trying to do is select a trace for a particular channel and then get the measurement data.

Working with a PNA, this would just be simple as setting the channel and trace, querying `CALC<num>:DATA? FDATA`, then get the frequency `CALC<num>:X?`.

How would a similar routine be programmed for the E5071C. The programming manual does not give much of an insight for how to retrieve data like this.

Comment: National Instruments (NI) actually does provide C-based Labwindows/CVI NI-VISA C drivers for many test instruments that are based on VISA standard (using SCPI commands), Agilent E5071C is listed here [Agilent Technologies / Keysight Technologies agena Analyzer](http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.download_page?p_id_guid=FE17565E9D861AB5E0340003BA7CCD71). From the C driver, you can find `agena_actExecuteAnalysis()` and `agena_dataReadAnalysisResult()` to understand how to use the `CALC` function, saving your time to craft a driver by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a VBA example program for the E5071C VNA on Keysight's webiste:

[[VBA Sample Program] Save Trace Data VBA](https://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?cc=GB&lc=eng&ckey=1537182&nid=-32496.1150429&id=1537182)

OR

This Microsoft Excel sample VBA program enables the ENA user to transfer the data to an external PC:

[[VBA Sample Program] ENA Data Transfer Program](https://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?cc=GB&lc=eng&ckey=2020276&nid=-32496.1150429&id=2020276)

This will have the right commands to use.